# Make my arduino accomplish task at specific time

Tags: arduino

I'm a newbie to arduino. What I need is make him do something at specific time, and go to sleep, so that it doesn't work excessively.

Specific task is: I want him to start a mechanism for feeding my gold fish, so in vacation time arduino should work for 10 days or more (this is reason for sleep mode).

When researching this problem, I came up with time interrupts, but I don't think this is best solution, because I want him do something at specific time, not to to interrupt his task.

Thank you for any kind of help :)

Comment: Get an RTC clock and set up an alarm interrupt.

Comment: Arduinos internal clock is not very precise, the longer it runs the more it will derive from the actual time (i have no experience how much though). One solution is to add an RTC module, as suggested, but both bring the additional problem that you need to tell the Arduino the current time in the first place, either via a display/buttons or via NTP over an ethernet module. The [Timer Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer) can help you evaluating the time and date. Nevertheless there are commercial feeders available for less than the costs of an Arduino. IMO it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: I linked to the wrong library. I actually meant the [Time Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time).

Comment: Thank you both, I'll research this RTC and timer library. I know that there are feeders available, but I want to play and make my own. :)

Comment: Will you be running battery or wall power?  Out of pure curiosity, what if the feeder actuated on the first run of the loop and it then entered a super long countdown until the arduino hardware reset itself?  Once it resets itself, it would enter the loop, feed and repeat.  Would eliminate the need for rtc.  The time would get reset every x hours, so the internal clock drift would be mitigated and I cant imagine that goldfish need to be fed at precise times.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Josh's solution of using the clock to reset the device, but [here's another idea](http://wyolum.com/syncing-arduino-with-gps-time/) if your fish will die if they aren't fed on the millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Use the millis() method. It will reset after 50 days but I don't think you will be traveling for so long...

```
unsigned long hours4nextFeeding = 8;
unsigned long lastTime = millis();
void loop() {
    if(millis() > (lastTime + (hours4nextFeeding*3600*1000))) {
        feedTheFish();
        lastTime = millis();
    }
    delay(60000);
}
```

Also you can use a light sensor (supercheaper) and feed the fish once a day when the sun rises

The code I just wrote is untested but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the standard Arduino board doesn't save that much power, as the power regulator and USB port (if present) draws significant power. But given that you use an external clock to trigger the device to wakeup, there's a simple arduino library, [Enerlib](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Enerlib), that you can use.

Engblaze has a [nice article](http://www.engblaze.com/hush-little-microprocessor-avr-and-arduino-sleep-mode-) on how to do it yourself, but if you're new to the arduino, you might not want to jump into AVR libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something easy like every 30 seconds starts an event of 20 seconds of duration :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);
#ifdef AVR
  Wire.begin();
#else
  Wire1.begin(); // Shield I2C pins connect to alt I2C bus on Arduino Due
#endif
  rtc.begin();

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
}
 boolean pumpOn = false;
void loop () {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    if(now.second()%30==0){ pumpOn=true;}
    if(now.second()%50==0){ pumpOn=false;}
    if(pumpOn)
      Serial.println("on");
}
}
```